# How can I change a hex color on a webpage with javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a web extension (Chrome, Firefox) and I want to know what JavaScript will replace a style element's color with a different color. There is a style section that has

```
<style> --toolbar-bg-color: #0087FF; </style>
```

and I want to make that just a white background (#FFFFFF). Is there an easy JavaScript command that might do this?

Comment: You could look for the element that uses this CSS variable and modify the variable as an inline style on the element. For example `document.querySelector('.your-element').style.setProperty('--toolbar-bg-color', '#fff');`

Answer (score 0):

If the parent element has an id you could do something like this:

```
let element = document.getElementById('parentElement');
element.style['--toolbar-bg-color'] = '#FFFFFF';
```

Try it and let me know how it goes :)

Comment: I am having a hard time finding a parent element id, sigh. The page is at cryptpad.fr/drive which intrigues me because it is a very private alternative to Google Docs/Sheets, but their color scheme with the light blue is unappealing so I am trying to find a way to replace the blue backgrounds with just white or very light gray, more like Google Docs/Sheets.  If anybody has an interest in checking it out, all you do is put in even a random username and random password for guest access, no email needed.